# Xubuntu: Disks utility (palimpsest) and Gparted not showing up anywhere after installation

Tags: installation, xubuntu, disk-utility

So I've downloaded Gparted and Disks from the software center. According to software center, they've both installed successfully... but they're nowhere to be found.

Even in my terminal:

```
$ palimpsest
palimpsest: command not found
```

I've looked in `usr/bin`... no "palimpsest", no "gnome-disk-utility".

In `usr/share/gnome-disk-utility` there's a bunch of `.ui` files.

According to Software Center, both programs are now installed in my computer, but it seems I've no way to find them. I've tried re-installing and restarting.

I'm on Xubuntu 32 bit.

Comment: Install them again using the Terminal.

Comment: `apt-get install gnome-disk-utility` yields `gnome-disk-utility is already the newest version`. -- As far as my computer is reporting, everything is installed, I just have no idea how to get to the software or where its path is.

Comment: Strange: if I log in using "XFCE session" then disks shows up in my applications finder. But not in a "Xubuntu session".

Comment: Some Gnome software is "hidden" in some sessions. I saw a question about that (how to hide software in one session but not in others) but I can't remember it.

Comment: hm. well I like the vanilla XFCE look and as far as I can tell everything that comes with the xubuntu package is available from an XFCE session, so I guess I'll just stick to XFCE sessions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As in [AJefferiss's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/239495/88802), it's `gnome-disks`, nowadays.

Compare the file contents list of the package [in 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/gnome-disk-utility/filelist) with the one [in 12.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/gnome-disk-utility/filelist). It appears that `palimpsest` has been renamed to `gnome-disks`, without leaving a symbolic link behind. I'm surprised to see that last part has happened.

Usually, the developers leave a link there to preserve compatibility. Well, my feeling about this is right, because, there you go, it's a bug!

- [LP Bug #1041665: gnome-disk-utility is missing palimpsest (renamed to gnome-disks)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1041665)

<sup>Make sure to mark yourself *affected* there by this bug if you feel this should be solved. At the moment of writing this has a very low priority and is unassigned...</sup>

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to find this utility as "Disks" under the Settings Manager. Otherwise, the command you want is `gnome-disks`.

Answer (score -1):

Settings-Manager > Panel > Select "Panel 0" > Click on "items".

Select "Application Menu" and click the little gear to edit the currently selected item.
On the new window, click "Edit Menu" button.

And then, everything you ever wanted happens! Simply add the software you want in the various menu items.

Answer (score -1):

Versions above 3.0.2 have been replaced with something that is totally different.  So for Ubuntu versions 12.10 and above, do this as root or sudo:

Add to /etc/apt/sources.lst:

deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

Run "apt-get update"

"apt-cache showpkg gnome-disk-utility" will show you the versions available.

Then install the specific version:
"apt-get install gnome-disk-utility=3.0.2-2ubuntu7"

Done!  To lock the version so it does not get upgraded automatically:

"apt-mark hold gnome-disk-utility"

Comment: -1. No need to downgrade versions; the application has just renamed. See the other answers.