# How can I launch Disk Utility after installing it?

Tags: disk-utility

I'm trying to run `gnome-disk-utility`. But I cannot seem to find it.

`sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility` says its already installed, as does the software manager, however running `gnome-disk-utility` or `palimpsest` gets me `command not found`.

I have tried reinstalling it (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall`, and `sudo apt-get remove` ... `sudo apt-get install`), which does no good.

```
whereis: palimpsest return empty
whereis: gnome-disk-utility returns /usr/share/gnome-disk-utility, a folder which contains nothing but *.ui files
```

So, what has gone wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I can't find gnome-disks anywhere in 14.04 through the terminal even after installing with apt-get :( And whereis returns: `gnome-disks:`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The command to run **gnome-disk-utility** is

```
gnome-disks
```

Comment: this is why applications should have the same launch name as their package name, like basically every other app out there

Answer (score 3):

Looks like in 13.04 it's just called the "disks" menu item from the ubuntu main menu.  And is installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

[Xubuntu: Disks utility (palimpsest) and Gparted not showing up anywhere after installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207943/xubuntu-disks-utility-palimpsest-and-gparted-not-showing-up-anywhere-after-in/239749#239749)

https://askubuntu.com/a/239749/284570

> As in [AJefferiss's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/239495/88802), it's `gnome-disks`, nowadays.
>
> Compare the file contents list of the package [in 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/gnome-disk-utility/filelist) with the one [in 12.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/gnome-disk-utility/filelist). It appears that `palimpsest` has been renamed to `gnome-disks`, without leaving a symbolic link behind. I'm surprised to see that last part has happened.
>
> Usually, the developers leave a link there to preserve compatibility. Well, my feeling about this is right, because, there you go, it's a bug!
>
> - [LP Bug #1041665: gnome-disk-utility is missing palimpsest (renamed to gnome-disks)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1041665)
>
> <sup>Make sure to mark yourself *affected* there by this bug if you feel this should be solved. At the moment of writing this has a very low priority and is unassigned...</sup>