# slow usb speed in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: usb

I have running dual boot of windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 in Lenovo g580. My laptop configured USB 3.0 . In windows7 USB speed is high (30-40 MB/sec), but in Ubuntu 13.04 its very very less (1-2 MB/sec). How can i improve this speed in Ubuntu.

Here I'm attaching out put file of `lsusb` and `dmesg|tail`

```
ramesh@ramesh-Lenovo-G580:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2e2 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2188:0ae1  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

ramesh@ramesh-Lenovo-G580:~$ dmesg|tail
[ 3271.475376] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 3271.475380] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 3286.988521] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 3288.196715] wlan0: authenticate with 58:93:96:1f:13:18
[ 3288.218574] wlan0: send auth to 58:93:96:1f:13:18 (try 1/3)
[ 3288.220503] wlan0: authenticated
[ 3288.223646] wlan0: associate with 58:93:96:1f:13:18 (try 1/3)
[ 3288.228688] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 58:93:96:1f:13:18 (capab=0x21 status=0 aid=8)
[ 3288.228718] wlan0: associated
[ 3288.228726] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer should help you [Slow USB 3.0 speeds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110304/slow-usb-3-0-speeds?rq=1).
Ubuntu is faster when copying files with the same file system format. Copying large folders from ext2(ubuntu 13 default default formatting) to NTFS(windows default) can give the effect you are experiencing.
You could:

- format the external hard disk to ext4
- divide the file you want to copy in 4 or more folders and copy each separately.
  A relatively small folder of 8Gb and 140000files can take up to 10minutes instead of 160seconds to copy, but if you copy the four sections separately it can take less than 200 seconds to complete.Optimal size for folder copy is aroud 500Mb, it drops to 30Mb/s after 1Gb and drops to 10Mb/s after 2Gb.

Comment: Could you explain why it takes longer to copy them all at the same time? Is it a limitation of the NTFS or ext4 filesystems? Is it just an issue of processing power/memory needed to convert? Something else?