# Do I have to install any additional driver for my usb 3 port in ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers, usb, performance

I installed ubuntu 14.04 lts in my new laptop (HP 250 G3 Notebook). It has a usb 3 port with it, but surprisingly the speed of usb 3 and usb 2 is same. I have attached the output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0226 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 248a:8564  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also attached two screen shot while I was transferring a file to my usb flash drive. My A-DATA Technology flash drive is usb 3 supported. Can anyone please give me a solution how to increase the speed, as it suppose to be for usb 3.

for usb 3 [image]

for usb 2 [image]

Comment: This may help : [Slow USB 3.0 speeds](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110304/slow-usb-3-0-speeds)

Comment: hey I did the banchmark test. it seems the writing speed is same for both the port but for reading speed usb 3 is faster then usb 2.