# The speed of USB 3.0 port is very slow

Tags: usb

When I copy files from USB storage to my hard disk, the speed is less than 400 kB/sec. I change my OS from ubuntu 16.04 to windows 10, the speed is about 35 MB/sec.

```
myzhao@myzhao-YNAO:~$ uname -a
Linux myzhao-YNAO 4.13.0-38-generic #43~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14     17:46:42 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

myzhao@myzhao-YNAO:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 24ae:1812 
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 0853:0111 Topre Corporation
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6713 Microdia
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
myzhao@myzhao-YNAO:~$ dmesg | grep usb
[240328.804985] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[240328.804993] usb 1-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 11
[240328.911183] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[240328.923935] usb 1-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[240337.218848] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[240337.367141] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0813
[240337.367148] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[240337.367153] usb 2-2: Product: USB3.0 Hub            
[240337.367157] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.        
[240337.749742] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[240337.899320] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2813
[240337.899328] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[240337.899333] usb 1-2: Product: USB2.0 Hub            
[240337.899337] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.        
[240338.209644] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[240338.324590] usb 1-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0853, idProduct=0111
[240338.324598] usb 1-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[240338.324603] usb 1-2.1: Product: Realforce 87
[240338.324608] usb 1-2.1: Manufacturer: Topre Corporation
[240338.327462] input: Topre Corporation Realforce 87 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/0003:0853:0111.0007/input/input31
[240338.386449] hid-generic 0003:0853:0111.0007: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Topre Corporation Realforce 87] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1/input0
[240338.477512] usb 1-2.2: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[240338.594849] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=24ae, idProduct=1812
[240338.594856] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[240338.594860] usb 1-2.2: Product: RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device
[240338.594864] usb 1-2.2: Manufacturer: RAPOO
[240338.597974] input: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.0/0003:24AE:1812.0008/input/input32
[240338.658319] hid-generic 0003:24AE:1812.0008: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.2/input0
[240338.663039] input: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.1/0003:24AE:1812.0009/input/input33
[240338.722334] hid-generic 0003:24AE:1812.0009: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.2/input1
[241578.147966] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 12
myzhao@myzhao-YNAO:~$ usb-devices

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh=16
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.13
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.13.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=11 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0c45 ProdID=6713 Rev=56.05
S:  Manufacturer=CN045G28724876BAB2KBA01
S:  Product=Integrated_Webcam_HD
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#= 13 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2109 ProdID=2813 Rev=02.21
S:  Manufacturer=VIA Labs, Inc.        
S:  Product=USB2.0 Hub            
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=13 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 14 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0853 ProdID=0111 Rev=00.01
S:  Manufacturer=Topre Corporation
S:  Product=Realforce 87
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=13 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#= 15 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=24ae ProdID=1812 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=RAPOO
S:  Product=RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=03 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0cf3 ProdID=e300 Rev=00.01
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 8
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=04.13
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.13.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=5000 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2109 ProdID=0813 Rev=02.21
S:  Manufacturer=VIA Labs, Inc.        
S:  Product=USB3.0 Hub            
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
myzhao@myzhao-YNAO:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 5000M
|__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
|__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
|__ Port 2: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 17, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 15, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
|__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
|__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
|__ Port 12: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
|__ Port 12: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 15, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
|__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
|__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
|__ Port 12: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
|__ Port 12: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

Comment: What have you researched, and what have you tried? There are many similar questions on this site already, e.g: [Slow USB 3.0 speeds](https://askubuntu.com/q/110304/301745)

Comment: Please add output of `lsusb -t` to the question.

Comment: I find this problem when I process some data, which are stored in a  Seagate 2T portable hard disk.

Comment: What file system is it on the  Seagate 2T portable hard disk? And what file system is there in the target partition (to where you want to copy the files)? I think you will get higher speed in Ubuntu, when you use linux file systems (compared to for example NTFS, which is a proprietary file system owned by Microsoft).

Comment: The file system of the portable hard disk is NTFS, and I want to copy files to an EXT4 partition.

Comment: In order to compare, I format a small flashdisk to EXT4. When I copy files to this flashdisk (EXT4 to EXT4), the speed is about 900 Kb/s. As a comparison, the speed is about 400 Kb/s when I copy files to the Seagate 2T portable hard disk (NTFS to EXT4). I think both are too slow.

Comment: I recently got a same problem. You are using VIA Usb Hub 2109:0813/2109:2813 - I have problem with it in Armbian. Direct connection is fast, but with hub it is very slow